# How to fix multiprocess issue in code given below?

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, computer-vision, multiprocessing

My main function is aligning images with the reference image. The function is working smoothly for single core. I had tried to multi-process the above problem to reduce the time, but it is taking same time as single core. I think same image is allotted to all the cores. How do I split different images in a folder to different cores to speed the process? Also tell me if there is any error in my code.

```
MAX_FEATURES = 50000
GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT = 1.00
def alignImages(refimage, input_path, output_path):
    im1 = cv2.imread(input_path)
    im1Gray = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    im2Gray = cv2.cvtColor(reference_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect ORB features and compute descriptors.

    #Machter Algo

    # Remove not so good matches
    numGoodMatches = int(len(matches) * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT)
    matches = matches[:numGoodMatches]

    # Draw top matches
    imMatches = cv2.drawMatches(im1, keypoints1, reference_image, 
    keypoints2, matches, None)

    # Extract location of good matches
    points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
    points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
    for i, match in enumerate(matches):
        points1[i, :] = keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt
        points2[i, :] = keypoints2[match.trainIdx].pt

    # Find homography
    h, mask = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2, cv2.RANSAC)

    # Use homography
    height, width, channels = reference_image.shape
    imReg = cv2.warpPerspective(im1, h, (width, height))
    f, e = os.path.splitext(output_path)
    cv2.imwrite(f + '.TIF',imReg) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    path = r'Path of folder to align images'

    dirs = os.listdir(path)
    array1 = []
    array2 = []
    array3 = []

    for i in dirs:
        input_path = path+'\\'+i
        reference_image = cv2.imread('Reference image path')
        array1.append(reference_image)
        array2.append(input_path)
        out = path +'\\'+'new\\'+i
        array3.append(out)

    z = list(zip(array1,array2,array3))
    p = Pool(12)
    p.starmap(alignImages,z,chunksize=28)
    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)
```

Comment: I would suggest not making your input be called `input` as that's the name of an inbuilt function which you're then redefining. How many cores does your machine actually have? And how long is your input list `z`? It may be that the `chunksize` argument is having an effect here.

Comment: I have changed the variable name as you suggested. I have a 12 core machine.

Comment: As suggested, I would try altering the chunksize and measuring your performance. Another consideration could be if the image processing is using a lot of memory and there is a lot of "swapping" going on, you may not see the increased performance you were expecting. So perhaps try adjusting the size of your pool. A simple comparison would be to try it without any parallelism and benchmark, then to try it with a pool of 2 processes. You could also move your benchmarking inside the processing function and print the time of each individual step to see if they are individually slower if using pool.

Comment: Passing the reference image around seems like a bottleneck.

Comment: @JanneKarila not the main problem. The performance is deteriorated due to a poor performance of how the work gets split / distributed among the Pool()-workers. Different Operating systems have different default Pool()-backend(s) that implicated different costs of moving data ( parameters ) into Pool()-worker from the central workflow orchestration side. The OpenCV-computing on arrays is smart and CPU/MEM-intensive, so poor orchestration may lead to worse run-times than a smart, pure-[SERIAL], vectorise-able code-runs. Going distributed is another way, yet beyond the scope of this post.